# Loading external text to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a project here at work i have to create a help file with several chapters and a lot of text in 1 big HTML file, but since the text has to be translated to different languages, i want to load the text from an external text file.

I've seen the topics like:

- loading external text from .txt to a html file
- jQuery load txt file .html()

But i can't manage to make it work.

As a test i created a very basic html file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="text">

 </div>
</body>
```

But even this doesn't work. I expected to see the text within the "textdoc.txt" file in the `<div id="text"> </div>`. But it remains blank. The text document is in the same directory as the html file. what am i doing wrong here?

As a side note, the system i create the help file for runs on IE7. does it even work for that?

Comment: You need to include jQuery file reference, `$(document).ready()` or may be basic tutorials to start.

Answer (score 3):

As MrN00b noted, I am assuming you have left out the inclusion of the jQuery js file itself? Please include it, if you have not already, as it is not implicitly part of a web page.

As your code precedes the item in the document it references (`id="text")`, you need to wait for the document to complete loading:

Use one of these so that your jQuery will wait for the DOM to finish loading:

### Traditional:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
     });
```

### Shortcut:

```
     $(function(){
         $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
     });
```

### Safe (locally scoped $):

```
     jQuery(function($){
         $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
     });
```

Note: *this looks a bit like an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) you might see, but it isn't.*

**The following is just to execute code with a scoped `$`, but not wait for loading.**

```
     (function($){
         // I am still run immediately as this is an IIFE!
         $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
     })(jQuery);
```

### e.g.:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
         $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="text">

 </div>
</body>
```

**Or, worst case, just put your code at the end of the `body` element instead of in the head**

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>

 <div id="text">

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     // This will now work as the element referenced must already be loaded
     $('#text').load("/textdoc.txt");
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: He also needs to add a reference to jQuery to his html - though I am assuming (or possibly hoping) that was merely an oversight in asking the question.

Comment: @MrN00b: I must admit I assumed that was just left out of the example! Will add note.

Comment: @MrNoob: They asked me to take on this task even though i'm not a programmer. I can use HTML for a bit, but JavaScript or jQuery are completely unknown to me. That is why i didn't include any file, cause i had no idea i had to do that. Thank your for your time to respond.